# Does angular support having multiple routes for a single path?

Tags: angular

I want to have multiple components associated to the root path in order to display one landing page view for anonymous users and an inbox for the authenticated users, without having to use manual navigation and path changes crutches.

I've tried to enable my scenario with a routing block like this:

```
{ path: '', component: LandingComponent, canActivate: [ ForbidAuthGuard ] },
{ path: '', component: LocationsComponent, canActivate: [ RequireAuthGuard ] }
```

Angular is indeed calling `ForbidAuthGuard`, which is failing on an authenticated user and therefore cancelling the navigation event altogether, ignoring the `RequireAuthGuard` route.

As implied by their conflicting names both guards are exclusive to each other so only one of the routes will ever be active, yet Angular seems to be ignoring the second route.

Is this mechanic viable at all? or Is there any other technique to achieve the end goal of the first paragraph?.

For completeness' sake I am using @angular/router and @angular/core with version 5.2.8.

Comment: there is a proper way to do achieve your goal, but it isn't "having multiple components associated with the root path".

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'd love to know more, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Yes, since you are open minded :-). The proper way is based upon abstracting authentication away so it just works and doesn't affect your day-to-day development. The mechanism is the HttpClient and  HTTPIntercepter provided by the API. You can find the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses with many many examples found via Google.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I do have an http interceptor to globaly set the auth header and handle implicit oauth token refresh, but i fail to see how it can participate in the routing process to determine which component is shown on the screen. Sorry.

Comment: Capture the 401/403 HTTP status codes in an intercepter and redirect to, perhaps a LandingComponent if not authorized, otherwise (if state has not been set/if first visit) redirect to maybe a LocationsComponent

Comment: @RandyCasburn That is actually a nice idea, but it's not that valid as the client should not even show the authenticated views or try to invoke the authenticated endpoints if no valid token data is found

Comment: Exactly my point - that is exactly the use case for intercepters. Please don't take my word for this. There is ample evidence on google.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
{ path: '', component: MyService.DoACheck() ? LandingComponent, LocationsComponent },
```

But that then would not use your guards.

The more common solution, I'm assuming, is the one you don't want:

Define one route with a guard.

In that route guard, determine if the user can access the route, if not, navigate to the other route.

Like this:

```
export  class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
    }

    checkLoggedIn(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Retain the attempted URL for redirection
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using an approach similar to this while someone helps me realize the vision i truly want for my routing. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you considered posting an issue/feature request to the Angular github repo?

Comment: Pretty sure this issue I'm having is just due to my limited knowledge and not due to an issue with Angular itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple Components associated to a single route:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-two-thirds">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Routing Config**

```
{
  path: 'my-single-url',
  children: [
    { path: '', component: ComponentOne },
    { path: '', component: ComponentTwo, outlet: 'aux' }
  ]
}
```